# Android Custom ArrayAdapter of list - Java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to android. I have implemented custom ArrayAdapter in my Android Application using view holder.
The getView() function of my ArrayAdapter is as follows for reference:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyClassViewHolder myClassViewHolder;
    MyClass myClass;
    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
        if(resourceId == R.layout.my_row_item) {
            myClassViewHolder = new MyClassViewHolder();
            myClassViewHolder.title = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            myClassViewHolder.switch = (Switch) row.findViewById(R.id.switch);
        }
    } else {
        myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    if(resourceId == R.layout.my_row_item) {
        myClass = (MyClass) myClassList.get(position); //myClassList sent as parameter to constructor of adapter
        if(myClassViewHolder != null && myClass != null) {
            myClassViewHolder.title.setText(myClass.getTitle());
            myClassViewHolder.switch.setChecked(myClass.isEnabled());
            myClassViewholder.id = myClass.getId();
            myClassViewHolder.switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    //GET ID OF THE ROW ITEM HERE
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

1. First of all I want to associate an id which is from database to
   every row item to perform actions on them. So please confirm if the
   way I have done is is right or wrong.
2. Secondly in the above code I have a String as title and a Switch in every row
   item. I want to set an onClickListener on each switch. On toggling
   the switch i want to get the id of the row item which is associated as per point 1.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I haven't described my problem properly.

Comment: why you need id for each row? while you can get its row number (position) already?

Comment: Well I want to perform some action in database related to the rowitem when I toggle the switch. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: set tag to each ID, and getTag() to recognize it?

Comment: Thank you Darpan. I achieved it by using tag just like you said. How do I approve your answer/comment?

Comment: Have posted my comment with an example and answer; You may mark/upvote now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set a tag for each row item and thus you can identify each row. Here is an example -

```
row.setTag(1);
```

and to retrive the tag -

```
row.getTag();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code looks  fine as for second part you should make a listener on switch and then get the id form the row and do switch from one id to another.

Comment: Thank you for replying. As you can see that I have set an onCheckedChangeListener on the switch. Will you please tell me how to do that exactly. How can I refer to the list item in the listener to the switch?